# Determine the similarity between two arrays of counts

Tags: python, arrays, distance, similarity

**The Problem:** I am trying to determine the *similarity* between two 1D arrays composed of counts. Both the **positions** and **relative magnitudes** of the counts inside the arrays are important.

```
X = [1, 5, 10, 0,  0, 0, 2]
Y = [1, 2,  0, 0, 10, 0, 5]
Z = [1, 3,  8, 0,  0, 0, 1]
```

In this case array X is more similar to array Z than array Y.

I have tried a few metrics including **cosine distance, earth movers distance and histogram intersection** and while cosine distance and earth movers distance work decently, only EMD really satisfies both of my conditions

I am curious to know if there are other algorithms / distance metrics out there that exist to answer this sort of problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One popular and simple method is root-mean-square, where you sum the squares of the differences between the elements, take the square root, and divide by the number of elements,  In your case, X vs Y produces 2.1, and X vs Z produces 0.4.

```
import math

X = [1, 5, 10, 0,  0, 0, 2]
Y = [1, 2,  0, 0, 10, 0, 5]
Z = [1, 3,  8, 0,  0, 0, 1]

def rms(a,b):
    return math.sqrt( sum((a1-b1)*(a1-b1) for a1,b1 in zip(a,b)))/len(a)

print(rms(X,Y))
print(rms(X,Z))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from dtaidistance import dtw
import numpy as np
X = [1, 5, 10, 0,  0, 0, 2]
Y = [1, 2,  0, 0, 10, 0, 5]
Z = [1, 3,  8, 0,  0, 0, 1]
def phase_corr(sig1, sig2):
    fft_sig1 = np.fft.fft(sig1)
    fft_sig2 = np.fft.fft(sig2)
    fft_sig2_conj = np.conj(fft_sig2)
    R = (fft_sig1 * fft_sig2_conj) / abs(fft_sig1 * fft_sig2_conj)
    r = np.fft.ifft(R)
    return np.real(r)

print(np.correlate(X, Z), np.correlate(Y, Z)) #cross-correlation
print(max(phase_corr(X, Z)), max(phase_corr(Y, Z))) 
print(dtw.distance(X, Z), dtw.distance(Y, Z)) #smaller distance means more similar
print(np.corrcoef(X, Z)[1,0], np.corrcoef(Y, Z)[1,0]) #Pearson correlation
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps manhattan distance works for you. The Manhattan distance between X and Y is 26, between X and Z is 5 and between Y and Z is 23.

```
from math import sqrt
def manhattan(x, y):
    return sum(abs(val1-val2) for val1, val2 in zip(x,y))
X = [1, 5, 10, 0,  0, 0, 2]
Y = [1, 2,  0, 0, 10, 0, 5]
Z = [1, 3,  8, 0,  0, 0, 1]
```

```
manhattan(X, Y)  # returns 26
manhattan(X, Z)  # returns 5
manhattan(Y,Z)   # returns 23
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`scipy.spatial.distance`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) for various distance metrics.

For instance, with the [Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance), we get that X is more similar to Z than to Y.

```py
from scipy.spatial import distance

X = [1, 5, 10, 0,  0, 0, 2]
Y = [1, 2,  0, 0, 10, 0, 5]
Z = [1, 3,  8, 0,  0, 0, 1]

print(distance.chebyshev(X, Y)) # returns 10
print(distance.chebyshev(X, Z)) # returns 2
```